# Get Text value after past value in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get text value when paste value in text box by using jQuery. Like i have paste value 123456 in text box then after paste i want get that value.

I was using .change but it give value after outfocus from text box. Keypress not working when past value.

Is anyone give me solution for this.or give me trick for achieve this.

Actually i am scanning barcode from barcode device after scan barcode value added on text-box. after scan i want to submit form that's why i am finding event that will fire after scan.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: Look for `onpaste Event`

Comment: @diiN__________ https://jsfiddle.net/k107d077/4/ please check here

Comment: @Rayon yes i want onpaste is any event in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "bind" function and "paste" event.

```js
$(".getval").bind("paste", function(e){
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="getval">
```

Comment: @muhamet thanks for your answer can you please let me know what is the use of originalEvent.clipboardData

Comment: @Sourabh We use the "originalEvent" expression used here and the "jQuery" event object ("e") to pass to the JavaScript event object. It then allows us to check the copying with "ClipboardData".

Comment: @Muhamet  thanks but i want to know is it will work with bar code scanner?

Comment: I did not understand what the barcode scanner was related to. Explaining exactly what you are doing can help. @Sourabh

Comment: Actually i am scanning barcode from barcode device after scan barcode value added on text-box. after scan i want to submit form that's why i am finding event that will fire after scan.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small timeout to get the pasted value.

```js
document.getElementById('getval').onpaste =function() {
setTimeout(() => {
let value = document.getElementById('getval').value;
console.log(value);
},200);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="getval">
```

Comment: Why do we need `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @Rayon its a hack of sorts; without setTimeout, for reasons I havent fully understood, there seems to be an issue in getting the value from the input box; hence a teeny tiny delay. If u have a solution for this, I am all ears.